# Can the binomial coefficient be extended to all scalars?

Tags: calculus, binomial-coefficients

What would it then mean to "$\pi$ choose $e$?

Is there a unique way to do it?

Does it have a practical application?

Comment: I suppose you could come up with some expression in terms of gamma functions, but I don't know what physical meaning it would have.

Comment: If $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $$z!=\Pi(z)$$ $\Pi(*)$ is the pi function.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Do you mean that it is congruent to the factorial function for positive integers? If so, would $(x,z)\in\mathbb{C},\binom{y}{x}=\frac{\Pi(y)}{\Pi(x)\Pi(y-x)}$? What would it mean then?

Comment: I don´t know an application, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments

Comment: Just in case you are wondering, using the extension from the gamma function, $\binom{\pi}{e}\approx 1.903568065729906338900833721481793534164058581505805576303447...$ What a reasonable interpretation is, though? Who knows?

Comment: Look up Gamma Function and Beta Function. Unavoidable in probability theory.